# Snowflake Connectors Require Region in Account Name (Locator)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, region

In the past week I've run across two tools (Hevo and Confluent) that require their cluster to be in the same region as the Snowflake account. This is understandable - since both are services they own the pipes and they want to manage their architecture. Unfortunately both parse the Snowflake account locator to determine the region. I'm using an account created under our Snowflake organization, which has an account name, but not the full account locator.

I consider this a tool as opposed to a Snowflake issue - they should do validation using Current_Region, but it's been a bit of a challenge to get the message across (particularly to Hevo). Is there some trick that will let me turn the account name into a full account locator so that I can solve this on the Snowflake side?

Comment: If you contact Support at Snowflake, they can probably provide you with the account locator of your account, which can still be used with those applications until they update how they are parsing the Snowflake URL.

Answer (score 1):

After a back and forth with Snowflake support, I was able to gather that for user created accounts, the account name and account locator are different. The account locator is somewhat random and can be determined by clicking on the username dropdown in the classic interface. Using this account locator, the URL can be constructed in the following format:
<account locator>.<region identifier>.snowflakecomputing.com

Region identifier details come from here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html#account-identifier-formats-by-cloud-platform-and-region

Note that this doesn't work when using the account name that is used when creating the account you have to use the account locator.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are an organization:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-organization-accounts.html

You can also find SELECT CURRENT_REGION() and use that to construct your URL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The trouble was that I did know the current region - I just didn't realize how the account name and account locator differed for user created accounts. I tried to provide some guidance in my answer.